# OAuth - is it safe to access secured resource and send back Token AND Token_Secret

Tags: oauth

I am confused about OAuth and its use of the token and token_secret when accessing protected resources.  It makes sense that a token and token_secret are sent back to the user for signing purposes when an access token is granted.  However, I've found 3 sites that use OAuth 1.0 require the token secret not only be used for signing but it should also be sent back with the token when accessing protected resources.  To me this makes absolutely no sense from a security viewpoint and seems to run counter to what is recommended in the OAuth specs: http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor13.

So am I missing something obvious or am I correct in believing that the token_secret should ONLY be used for signing and should never be sent back to the server.

Comment: What APIs return access tokens with the response?

Comment: I had found 3 sites and contact them respectively to see why they are doing it.  From your comment, do you agree that the token_secret should NOT be sent back when accessing protected resources and that it should only be used for signing?  Or am I missing the point?  I'm still familiarizing myself with the ins and outs of OAuth so it could very well be that I am wrong.  Just trying to understand what is the correct usage.

Comment: The way I understand the OAuth protocol, you are correct: the token and token_secret are used to generate signatures and should not be sent across the wire after being received by the client.

Comment: The token is generally sent across the wire but the secret should not. One exception is refresh tokens where short lived secrets will be returned when requested with a long lived secret signature.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if maybe I am mistaking a protected resource request for a refresh token request.  I'm going to have to recheck.  Thanks for pointing that out.